# Different area values for same polygon in ArcGIS Pro 3.2.2 vs QGIS 3.28.4

Tags: qgis, arcgis-pro, geometry, area

When I calculate the area of a polygon in QGIS using the **area($geometry)** function in the field calculator (and also when using the "add geometry attributes" function in the processing toolbox) I get one value. When I bring the same polygon into ArcGIS Pro and use the **Calculate Geometry** function for Area (not using geodesic) I end up with a different value.

This is not making any sense to me as to why this is happening.  I am not using a geodesic calculation for either area value.  Its the same polygon in the same file with the same coordinate system etc.

The "area1" field was calculated using QGIS and the "area2" field was calculated using ArcGIS Pro.  File link is provided below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-T0ZH-P6IybnRd0mEwTOovjHvO9Xjus6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: are you setting projections in qgis/arcgis to NAD_1983_10TM_AEP_Forest for Canada - Alberta?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same settings for both.

Comment: In QGIS, the `$area` command looks at your project properties and calculates the area based on how you have set up your QGIS project. Go to Project Properties -> General and under Measurements check ellipsoid and units for area calculation, which is used regardless of your data’s projection or CRS.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of different areas in different softwares.

Answer (score 0):

It may be doing geodesic by default, even though you aren't expecting it to do so.  Try deliberately calculating each using geodesic measurement and see if it comes up matching the other value.  I had this problem with a Length measurement once.